# Does Gmail API Provides any flag for detecting password change on the authorized account?

Tags: gmail-api

Is there any flag in Gmail API or Last password changed date may be, by which I can determine the change of password for an authorized account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/user-accounts#password_change

You should be able to hit this endpoint to retrieve password changes on emails within your domain.